# Routing optional bool values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a MVC controller action method like this

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(bool special = false)
{
   // process the special value in some special way...
   return View();
}
```

I want to access this action using two different links which differ only by the special flag, and I want to pass the flag as a human-readable route value. 
To be more precise, the links should look like this:

```
SomeController/DoSomething
SomeController/DoSomething/Special
```

Currently I have created action links:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Just do it", "DoSomething", "SomeController")
@Html.ActionLink("Do it in a special way", "DoSomething", "SomeController", new { special = true}, null)
```

and this code generates links like this:

```
SomeController/DoSomething/Special
SomeController/DoSomething?special=True
```

Obviously, I need a special route for the second link to become `SomeController/DoSomething/Special` but all my attempts have failed because in one MapRoute attempt it ignored my special flag, and in another MapRoute attempt it made both links to become `SomeController/DoSomething/Special` although I did not specify the special route value for the first ActionLink (it just picked it up from routes, I guess).

What is the right way to map the bool `special` to a URL `SomeController/DoSomething/Special` and make ActionLink to generate correct links?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming default routes are setup, you could generate your anchors like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Just do it", 
    "DoSomething", 
    "SomeController"
)

@Html.ActionLink(
    "Do it in a special way", 
    "DoSomething", 
    "SomeController", 
    new { id = "Special" }, 
    null
)
```

and your controller action might now look like this:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string id)
{
    bool special = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(id);

    // process the special value in some special way...
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this in your route config

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{Category}/{Name}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", Category= UrlParameter.Optional, Name= UrlParameter.Optional }
```

for detail please check http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=814